# How to add tr:nth-child inside tag table?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

Content my controller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class AutoLoadDiv extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('ngoding/AutoLoad');
    }

    public function getData() {

        $this->load->library('table');
        $err = file_get_contents("application\logs\log.php");
        $filestr = preg_replace(array('/(^|\R)ERROR\s*-\s*/', '/(^|\R)(.*?)\s*-->\s*/'), array('$1', '$1$2 '), $err);
        $arraySpacing = nl2br($filestr);
        $arr = explode("\n", $arraySpacing);

        $output = '<table style="tr:nth-child(even){background-color#FFF;} tr:nth-child(odd){background-color:#CCC;}", border="1px solid #dddddd;" >'; 
        for ($i = count($arr)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $output.="<tr><td>$arr[$i]</td></tr>"; 
        }
        $output.="</table>"; 
        echo $output; 


        }
    }
```

I have problem to add color background every row is different row, I found my answer but not working , that answer is add code inside `tr:nth-child(even)` and `tr:nth-child(odd)` ,how to add `tr:nth-child(even)` and `tr:nth-child(odd)` in tag  ?

Comment: can not add tag <style> in controller

Comment: oke thank you,  working now

Comment: your comment cannot to vote

Comment: why  I should flag your comment  , your comment not violate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend another `$output` that contains the stylesheet, that is like :

```
$output = '<style> tr:nth-child(even){background-color#FFF;} tr:nth-child(odd){background-color:#CCC;} </style>';
$output .= '<table border="1px solid #dddddd;" >';
```